# C pipe not functioning with large writes

Tags: c, pipe

Wrote a little script to work with `php5-cgi` using `fork()`,`exec()` and pipes. Script below works well when output of `php5-cgi` is small. But when it's considerably large (when using `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in the input file), it does not return anything.

```
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  int status;
  int link[2];
  char out[4096];
  char * arg[3]={"php5-cgi","a.php",0};
  if (pipe(link)==-1){
    perror("pipe");
  }
  int pid=fork();
  if (!pid){
    dup2 (link[1], 1);
    close(link[0]);
    execvp("php5-cgi", arg);
  } else {
    waitpid(pid, &status,0);
    close(link[1]); // parent doesn't write
        char reading_buf[1];
        while(read(link[0], reading_buf, 1) > 0){
            write(1, reading_buf, 1);
        }
        close(link[0]);
  }
  printf("%s\n", "end");
  return 0;
}
```

I assume this is due to overflow of pipe. I there any way to fix this issue? Or is there any alternatives to deal with large ouput?

Comment: Split up the data you write into smaller chunks?

Comment: First thing to do, always: check return values of all your system calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pipe buffer is relatively small, usually a few Kbytes.  The child can write to it until the buffer is full; then further writes will block until some of the data has been read.

Your parent calls `waitpid` before attempting to read from the pipe.  So it is waiting for the child to terminate.  But if the child is blocked trying to write, it will never terminate.  So you never get past the `waitpid` in this case.

What you probably want to do is move the `waitpid` after the `read/write` loop.  Then the child can continue writing more data as you read it.  When the `read()` finally fails, it is likely because the child has exited and closed its end of the pipe.  So you can do `waitpid` at that time to get the exit status and reap the zombie.

Also, check the return values of all your system calls!  And compile with warnings turned on (this will alert you that you forgot to `#include <sys/wait.h>`).

Comment: Moving ```waitpid``` worked! But it means that there is no guarantee that I will get whole output from exec to the parent thread. Am I correct?

Comment: @paarandika: No, not correct.  You will get the whole output.  Why do you think you would not?  The `read` in the parent will read from the pipe buffer, but if it becomes empty, `read` will block until the child writes some more.  However, if the buffer is empty and the child has closed the pipe or exits, `read` will stop blocking and return 0.  So your loop will not terminate until all the data written by the child has been read.

Comment: I thought once the pipe is empty, read returns even though child has not closed the pipe. BTW at the end of child process, does pipe automatically gets closed? Because in my code I have no chance to close it.

Comment: @paarandika: "I thought once the pipe is empty, read returns even though child has not closed the pipe." Well, that is not true, unless you open it in non-blocking mode (and even then it will return -1 with errno = EAGAIN; `read` only returns 0 when the pipe has been closed).  And yes, when the child process exits, all its open files (including pipes) are closed.